# ios - Adding single gesture recognizer to multiple labels

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating dynamic labels in scroll view and I want to add single gesture recognizer to all these dynamically generated labels. 
   I am creating gesture as following

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(handlePan:)] ;
```

Now I want to add this gesture to multiple labels. Is it possible to add same gesture to dynamically created labels ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this..its working for me

```
NSMutableArray *arrayForLabels=   [NSMutableArray array];
[arrayForLabels addObject:label];
[arrayForLabels addObject:label1];

// enable touch delivery
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
label1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


for (UILabel *myLabel in arrayForLabels) {

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(handlePan:)] ;

    [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead u can do one thing
Put all your labels in an array `myLabelArray`

```
NSArray *myLabelArray;
```

then add following code.
every time it will create a new instance of gesturerecognizer.

```
for (UILabel *myLabel in myLabelArray) {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(handlePan:)] ;
    [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```